# How to reverse an integer vector efficiently?

Tags: r, reverse, rcpp

**UPDATE**

***BUG*: there was a bug in `rev2` and it is fixed now.**

`rev1` and `Rcpprev1` are removed.

I have also included different functions and made modifications according to the comments and answers.

Conclusion: `rev4` is the best for my purpose, `RcppRev3` is better for long vector.

---

I have a program which requires reversing an integer vector (fixed length) many times. I profiled the code, the `rev` function took up about 30% of the total time. I was very surprised by the slow performance of the function `rev` in R. So I decided to compare the base R `rev` with some other alternatives

```
library(Rcpp)
library(microbenchmark)
rev2 = function(x){
    nx = length(x)
    y = vector("numeric", nx)
    for(i in 1:nx) y[i] = x[nx-i+1]
    y
}
rev3 = function(x){
    x[length(x):1]
}
rev4 = function(x){
    .subset(x, length(x):1)
}
```

Rcpp equivalence:

```
sourceCpp(code='
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector Rcpprev2(IntegerVector x){
    int nx = x.size();
    IntegerVector y(nx);
    for(int i = 0; i<nx; i++){
        y[i] = x[nx-i-1];
    }
    return(y);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector RcppRev3(IntegerVector x) {
  return rev(x);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> CppRev(std::vector<int> & x) {
  std::reverse(x.begin(), x.end());
  return x;
}

')
```

Microbenchmark:

```
> x = c(1L,2L,3L,4L)
> microbenchmark(rev(x), rev2(x), rev3(x), rev4(x), Rcpprev2(x),  RcppRev3(x), CppRev(x))
Unit: nanoseconds
        expr  min     lq median     uq   max neval
      rev(x) 4614 5501.0 6086.5 8208.0 32860   100
     rev2(x) 5765 6965.0 7803.0 8784.5 28637   100
     rev3(x) 1013 1351.0 1521.5 1985.5  9977   100
     rev4(x)  961 1317.0 1485.5 1728.5 16492   100
 Rcpprev2(x) 2008 2360.0 2558.5 3075.5 17342   100
 RcppRev3(x) 2045 2377.5 2607.5 3718.0  9184   100
   CppRev(x) 2279 2668.0 2947.0 3381.0 35614   100
```

It turns out the the fastest method is the pure R method `rev4`, it is even faster than the `Rcpp` functions.

Let's consider longer vector.

```
> x = rep(c(1L,2L,3L,4L), 1000)
> microbenchmark(rev(x), rev2(x), rev3(x), rev4(x), Rcpprev2(x),  RcppRev3(x), CppRev(x))
Unit: microseconds
        expr      min        lq    median        uq      max neval
      rev(x)   26.887   29.9425   39.2165   50.4080   71.614   100
     rev2(x) 3899.577 4195.3530 4370.5410 4743.3585 6117.387   100
     rev3(x)   22.092   24.4405   25.8340   27.8230   51.602   100
     rev4(x)   22.346   24.3150   25.8800   28.9425   90.666   100
 Rcpprev2(x)    6.039    7.6405    8.4530   11.6720   31.054   100
 RcppRev3(x)    5.384    6.1425    6.7395    8.3295   47.981   100
   CppRev(x)   10.462   12.0375   13.4130   17.6725   58.012   100
```

Rcpp functions are much better for long vectors.

Comment: Is it normal for the max timing to be 10 times longer than the median?

Comment: You can probably ignore the min and max cases, since the functions are fast, there could be a lot of variations.

Comment: Side question: Why do you have to reverse the vector so many times? Seems there would be a way to program around that, for example using your `x[length(x):1]`. Since you said it was fixed length, you could even dispense with the `length` calculation each time.

Comment: I have an optimization algorithm that require swapping two random indexes of a vector many times. I was using the `rev` function, but it was way way to slow..

Comment: Note that `rev.default` is already just `if (length(x)) x[length(x):1L] else x` so what you're capturing when reversing these small vectors with `rev` is the cost of function (S3) dispatch in R.

Comment: @KevinUshey, thanks for pointing the S3 dispatch thing.

Comment: @user2357112 max time might be much longer sometimes if garbage collection took place while running code.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing approaches which allocated new memories in copy, and those who do not.

I would try instantiating a `std::vector<int>` from the object pointer, and calling the appropriate reverse method of the C++ vector.  And then there is of course the Rcpp sugar method ...

So two more added:

```
R> microbenchmark(rev(x), rev1(x), rev2(x), rev3(x), Rcpprev1(x), Rcpprev2(x), 
+                 RcppRev3(x), CppRev(x))
Unit: microseconds
        expr   min     lq median      uq      max neval
      rev(x) 7.676 9.1070 9.9870 11.1445   71.559   100
     rev1(x) 1.446 1.9565 2.1580  2.4280   23.310   100
     rev2(x) 4.333 5.2875 5.9305  6.4335   17.458   100
     rev3(x) 1.229 1.6875 1.9310  2.1115   12.841   100
 Rcpprev1(x) 1.949 2.5440 2.8875  3.3655 7313.028   100
 Rcpprev2(x) 1.686 2.0840 2.6260  3.1960 2632.929   100
 RcppRev3(x) 1.544 2.0770 2.6130  2.9330   15.722   100
   CppRev(x) 1.986 2.6100 3.0530  3.6035   14.091   100
R>
```

But I suspect that with `n=4` you have little to measure here.

*Edit:* Here is an updated version reflecting Kevin's excellent point about `()` versus `[]`, and adding Randy's new `rev4` -- and running it all on meaningful vectors.
*Edit 2:* Still had one `()` where I needed `[]`. The `[]` is close to the Rcpp sugar performance but not quite there.

```
R> microbenchmark(rev(x), rev2(x), rev3(x), rev4(x), Rcpprev2r(x),
+                 Rcpprev2s(x), RcppRev3(x), CppRev(x))
 Unit: microseconds
          expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
        rev(x) 3505.205 3603.892 4307.269 4581.047 45761.91   100
       rev2(x)  273.258  294.350  341.571 1258.093 42992.72   100
       rev3(x) 3489.653 3573.588 4462.155 4545.285 46253.93   100
       rev4(x) 3481.903 3575.505 4409.817 4567.506 48873.70   100
  Rcpprev2r(x) 3433.918 3482.274 3507.504 3554.779  4519.62   100
  Rcpprev2s(x)  364.481  379.853  403.149  484.366  1684.71   100
   RcppRev3(x)  269.145  283.750  290.870  346.462 42867.46   100
     CppRev(x)  907.719  963.175  991.787 1126.783  2313.97   100
 R>
```

The sugar version still looks good to me.

For completeness, my [updated, twice] file is below.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector Rcpprev2r(IntegerVector x){
    int nx = x.size();
    IntegerVector y(nx);
    for(int i = 0; i<nx; i++){
        y(i) = x(nx-i-1);
    }
    return(y);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector Rcpprev2s(IntegerVector x){
    int nx = x.size();
    IntegerVector y(nx);
    for(int i = 0; i<nx; i++){
        y[i] = x[nx-i-1];
    }
    return(y);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector RcppRev3(IntegerVector x) { 
  return rev(x);
} 

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> CppRev(std::vector<int> & x) { 
  std::reverse(x.begin(), x.end());
  return x;
}
```

The R part is below:

```
/*** R
library(Rcpp)
library(microbenchmark)
x = rep(c(1L,2L,3L,4L), each=1e5)
rev2 = function(x){
    nx = length(x)
    y = vector("numeric", nx)
    for(i in nx) y[i] = x[nx-i+1]
    y
}
rev3 = function(x){
    x[length(x):1]
}
rev4 = function(x){
    .subset(x, length(x):1)
}
microbenchmark(rev(x), rev2(x), rev3(x), rev4(x), Rcpprev2r(x), 
               Rcpprev2s(x), RcppRev3(x), CppRev(x))
*/
```

Comment: If I knew you were answering I wouldn't have bothered ;)

Comment: No, it is complementary.  We should try the two I added to the better input vector you created, and through out his corner solutions which work only when n==4.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. Just want to add one point, there was a bug in `rev2` which makes it suspiciously fast.

Comment: Going faster with a modernized sugar implementation in Rcpp11. https://gist.github.com/romainfrancois/10849651

Answer (score 3):

FYI: There is a cost in using `operator()` instead of `operator[]` when indexing `Rcpp` vectors. This is because `operator()` uses the [offset](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h#L255) function, which does bounds checking, unlike `operator[]`. See:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector RcppRev(IntegerVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  IntegerVector output = no_init(n);
  for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    output[i] = x[n - i - 1];
  }
  return output;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector RcppRev2(IntegerVector x){
    int nx = x.size();
    IntegerVector y(nx);
    for(int i = 0; i<nx; i++){
        y(i) = x(nx-i-1);
    }
    return(y);
}

/*** R
library(microbenchmark)
x <- as.integer(rnorm(1E7))
identical( rev(x), RcppRev(x) )
identical( rev(x), RcppRev2(x) )
microbenchmark( times=5, 
  rev(x),
  RcppRev(x),
  RcppRev2(x)
)
*/
```

`sourceCpp` on this gives me:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('~/Desktop/rev.cpp')

> library(microbenchmark)

> x <- as.integer(rnorm(1E7))

> identical( rev(x), RcppRev(x) )
[1] TRUE

> identical( rev(x), RcppRev2(x) )
[1] TRUE

> microbenchmark( times=5, 
+   rev(x),
+   RcppRev(x),
+   RcppRev2(x)
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min        lq   median        uq      max neval
      rev(x) 54.987311 55.261393 55.48561 56.083582 70.88035     5
  RcppRev(x)  8.375551  8.458457  8.70446  8.800677 63.12635     5
 RcppRev2(x) 75.398164 75.733779 75.74356 76.027000 76.59727     5
```

Comment: Very good point but Rcpp Sugar still beats it, see my (twice updated) answer.

Comment: Kevin, `operator[]` also has cost. it is lower, but still. Using iterators as what sugar does (esp in Rcpp11) gives you best performance. https://gist.github.com/romainfrancois/10849651

Answer (score 2):

Your conclusion is wrong. For large vectors `rev1` versions of both R and RCpp are impractical. `rev2` comes out to be fast.

```
x = rep(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 1e+05)
microbenchmark(rev(x), rev2(x), rev3(x), Rcpprev1(x), Rcpprev2(x))
## Unit: microseconds
##         expr      min        lq    median        uq       max neval
##       rev(x) 2159.888 2202.9270 2235.3715 2515.2895 32350.315   100
##      rev2(x)  201.621  221.3185  229.9265  255.9155  1577.871   100
##      rev3(x) 2139.362 2191.5050 2212.6935 2907.7710 32202.328   100
##  Rcpprev1(x)    1.655    3.8075    9.6010   13.5740    18.871   100
##  Rcpprev2(x) 4784.596 4857.7615 4892.3580 4957.4130  5777.800   100
```

**Update**

Here are updated benchmark using Dirk's `CppRev` and `Rcpprev3` functions.

`RcppRev3` is best here.

```
microbenchmark(rev(x), rev2(x), rev3(x), Rcpprev2(x), RcppRev3(x), CppRev(x))
## Unit: microseconds
##         expr      min        lq   median       uq       max neval
##       rev(x) 2157.902 2227.2605 2502.874 2975.143 32623.777   100
##      rev2(x)  202.945  231.7475  250.453  829.822  1042.865   100
##      rev3(x) 2127.112 2205.9070 2321.946 2947.996 32239.076   100
##  Rcpprev2(x) 4805.453 4878.6190 4924.637 5018.495  5846.661   100
##  RcppRev3(x)  189.040  206.0900  222.478  797.874  1135.232   100
##    CppRev(x) 1368.304 1410.6810 1432.035 1489.972 31546.151   100
```

Comment: Agreed, I pretty much said the same thing.

Comment: The Rcpp sugar implementaion `RcppRev3` looks pretty good too.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - yes indeed

Comment: Thanks for the comparison, Rcpp sugar seems to be the best universally. It is strange that `rev2` outperforms `rev3` for long vector.

Comment: conclusion: the universal winner is `Rcpp sugar` and for small n, `rev3` seems better.